# How do I allow user to select, but not edit, text in an excel userform control whose width is smaller than the text?

Tags: excel, textbox, userform, vba

**Context** 
I want the user to review some selections they made earlier. So I display some text describing each selection on a separate control in a userform. Some of the text on the controls is long, extending beyond the width of the control. This is fine; I just want the user to be able to see all of the text without being able to edit it. To do this, I use textboxes that are "Locked" (i.e. not editable) but "Enabled" (i.e. selectable). This way, they can just click and either mouse-drag or arrow-key over to scroll through all the text.

**Problem** 
The (small, aesthetic) problem is that when the user clicks in one of the textboxes, they get a blinking cursor, which is misleading as that is normally associated with an *editable* textbox.

**Possible solutions** 
Ideally, there would be some way of removing the blinking cursor, while still allowing selection but not edition. However, I'm open to other alternatives that don't have to do with changing the width, or having a scrollbar (the textbox is too short to fit a scrollbar). The best alternative I have so far is changing the background color to a gray to make it slightly more clear that it's not editable.

P.S. I'm very familiar with VBA, so if that's part of the solution, I'm cool with that.

Thanks all!

Comment: Use a label instead of textbox to show the descriptions?

Comment: I tried using a label but it didn't seem like I couldn't select all the text beyond the end of the label.

Comment: label doesn't allow selection of text.

Comment: Soooo, that doesn't really help then. I need to allow selection but not edition.

Comment: In short, you want user to be able to select but you do not want to show the blinking cursor?

Comment: I can hide the blinking cursor in the textbox using the `HideCaret` API but then it will also disable the selection. The only alternative that I can see without using a second control is to select all text by default in that textbox's event (Be it Enter, KeyDown, Keypress etc)

Comment: I don't mind using a second control. But the hidden textbox trick didn't work as discussed in the answer below.

Comment: Here is one more logic that I thought of... When the user "enters" the textbox, all text will be selected and then user can then use the Right/Left arrow key to scroll the selection without showing the blinking caret.
That is possible by storing the textbox text in a variable and then trimming of text and displaying and selecting that when the user presses the right arrow key. Similarly the reverse should happen when the user presses the left key. It is more like a TICKER

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solved it by using [these instructions](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/remove-cursor-excel-vba-textbox-42485.html) to create a hidden textbox that the cursor automatically appeared in (invisible to the user).

Comment: I must be missing something, because I keep getting the following error "Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus". Just to be clear, I'm using an unlocked, enabled, invisible textbox, per the link's instructions. So this solution seems fundamentally flawed (i.e. invisible textboxes can't get the focus).

Comment: Try setting the focus when it's still visible. If that doesn't work, you may be able to move the second box off screen.

Comment: I also tried creating and hiding a second textbox, not by messing with the "invisible" property but by changing the dimensions, backcolor, and hiding behind other controls. That still didn't work exactly as described in the instructions. The reason is that there's nothing saying one of my main textboxes shouldn't get control when clicked AFTER the userform is activated. I tried the "Enter" procedure, but this prevents selection, since every time the user clicks the main textbox, the second textbox gets the focus.

Comment: I can get a little closer if I use the MouseDown procedure, but then if the user first jus clicks into the main textbox, it gets the focus and thus the blinking cursor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.